# Repeat row wise a string number of times in corresponding column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Here is a screen shot of some data:
[image]

I would like to build a new column that is the the string in column A the total number of times it occurs.

So entry "Too expensive" would be on 26 rows then under that would start "Don't want it" taking up 6 rows, then "too expensive" (different since lower case) would take up another 6 + 5 from row 14.

So just a new column that is each string the number of times it appears. Inverse pivot tabling, if you will.

How would I do that? I tried playing with rept() but that put everything in one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, see if this works ?

```
=ArrayFormula(trim(transpose(split(query(rept(A2:A&char(10),B2:B),,50000), char(10)))))
```

Comment: Had another use case come up and this works beautifully with less steps in between - thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like most likely you first need a helper column to basically unique the values so in column C you would put :

```
=UNIQUE(A:A)
```

and for the sake of explanation, if you want to see how it breaks down, in column D you can put

```
=sum(FILTER(B2:B,exact(C2,A2:A)))
```

The reason for using exact , is that otherwise it wont be case sensitive.

Once you have your final number for the `REPT` function you consutruct your repeatable value with a delimiter:

```
=rept(C2&";",D2)
```

This helps out split them out properly later into a column, if you rept the value with out the semicolon you will see the same result your describing up top where they are all mashed together.

Currently at this point this is what you would see:

[image]

To save some space I nest the sum filter into the rept function so I can remove column D:

```
=REPT(C2&";",sum(FILTER(B2:B,exact(C2,A2:A))))
```

I then join all those and split them out one last time using the `;` as a delimiter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",D2:D4),";"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Thanks also for breaking it up into smaller pieces so I could follow. Actually, my data set is ~17k rows and I receive an error on the final formula "Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.". So I tried breaking it into smaller ranges, but even on e.g. =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",D2:D1000),";")) I still get that message. Do any alternatives to using join() come to mind?

Comment: trying out a couple things - def didnt realize it would be 17K rows lol - you have 17k unique rows or 17k to start with?

Comment: Sorry 17k to start with so total rows will be higher

Comment: Thanks agin for your help. The 50k limit seems a common problem from Googling around. I amended your last formula: =transpose(SPLIT(QUERY(E8:E16692,,99999),";"))
It took a very long time to run but did the trick. Thanks!
Accepting the answer sine it does work but with smaller ranges of data, if larger data set can use query() which seems a bit like a hack since using the headers in a query function not for intended purpose

Comment: Yeah sorry about that but glad you got a work around :)